# Keeping track of promises in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, promise

Let's say I have a an array I'm iterating using a forEach loop.
For each element I am running a Firestore `set()` function.

I want to get a callback once all Promises are fulfilled.

Is there a better way of doing this than pushing all promises to an array and then using `Promise.all()`?

```
var promArr = [];

arr.forEach(elem => {
   promArr.push(db.collection('col').doc(elem).set({
     key: 'value'
   }))
})

Promise.all(promArr).then(_ => {
   console.log('All promises fulfilled.')
})
```

Comment: No, this is the correct way of doing it. The only way you could improve it, would be to let your `doc` function take an array of element.

Comment: No, there is no a better way to do what you want. Specially because a `forEach()` loop cannot be interrupted

Comment: No, this is the best way to do it. As you get the details of all calls made in one

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` to save a line:

```
const promArr = arr.map(elem => {
   return db.collection('col').doc(elem).set({
     key: 'value'
   });
});
```